# Fail to get DB connection from camel route

Tags: java, spring, oracle, apache-camel

I am noticing a very strange behavior when running an Apache camel route like below:

```
from("direct:daily-extract")
        .id("direct:daily-extract")
        .setHeader("runDate", constant("20170606"))
        .to("sql-stored:pkg_etls.load_exchange_rates(VARCHAR ${headers.runDate})?dataSource=#myDataSource")
....
```

Now I can observe the following:

1. I have an integration test for this route and it is running OK
2. I run this route as a standalone java app on my windows developer machine and it is running OK
3. When installed on a linux machine on a test environment it blows up with the exception below

   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection reset)
4. Other routes that use exactly the same data source run perfectly on the same linux machine. In fact `myDataSource` is configured in only one place.

Can you please help me with any suggestions as whatever I tried did not work.

What I tried so far without any luck was:

1. Updated camel version to the latest: 2.19.0
2. Tried two ojdbc7 versions: 12.1.0.2 and 12.1.0.1
3. Used two data sources: `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` and `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**

There is no oracle client installed on the linux box. Here is my data source configuration:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Are your database and app on the same linux host? This appears more of a connection issue.

Comment: No they are not running on the same linux machine. I agree it seems a connection issue but it is very odd other extracts work just fine. Plus it is odd it all works OK from my dev machine even if I am connecting to the same database.

Comment: Okay, do you have any sql client on the linux host to test the sql connection? If not, can you telnet/ssh to the database host?

Comment: Are the other routes(which works) already in production? What is the maximum pool size? Sounds like you are running out of connections in the pool. Run a `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on mysql. How is the datasource configured?

Comment: Are you sure that the other routes which use this dataSource work perfectly fine?

Comment: I haven't tested them myself but I am 100% sure the testers marked them as working. Will test it again myself and update.

Comment: I can confirm that I tested it myself and it is just that route that is having the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very odd behavior and thanks google, we would be dead without you :-)
The explanation and fix is on this [Oracle Community Article](https://community.oracle.com/thread/943911?tstart=0&messageID=3793101).

Comment: the link is broken. Any alternative?